# login/logout for only one page

Tags: login

I have a site that is visible to the public except for one page. Therefore, I have turned off the admin bar completely and I'm not using any widgets or sidebar. The admin has to type the full URL to get into the admin section.

The one page in question requires login/logout only for that page, not for Wordpress in general.  The only one who has access to their profile is the admin. Setting page visibility to password-protected is not an option. I need unique user ids and passwords.

When selecting the page from the main menu, the user will be asked for username and password. A successful login will display the contents without a redirect as well as a logout link.

I've searched this site, as well as many others, but haven't found any answers. And none of the plugins do this. Does anyone out there have any ideas?

Thanks!

Update: I just found the Remove Dashboard Access plugin. So that takes care of one thing. Now I just need to figure out how to do the login form without a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wp_login_form()` to display the login form anywhere. You could hook into the `the_content` filter to replace the content of the page with the form when they're not logged in.